# Wordpress-How can I add custom image links into the top bar?

Tags: css, wordpress, header, themes

I am using Bota theme with Wordpress and am trying to add custom image links to the top bar but cannot seem to figure it out.
I do not even know which code to show you as I cannot find where to implement the code. 
If you could even point me in a direction it would be great. Thanks

Comment: google wordpress theme's hierarchy and also template hierarchy

Answer (score 0):

You have to edit theme's *style.css* from the admin panel (Appearance -> Editor and find the style.css file to edit it). Find the selector for the navigation item. It should be this one if I am looking at the same theme: *.main-navigation li* and set a *background-image* for it. This should solve it.

PS: Before editing the file make sure you make a local copy of the css file so you can have backup of it.